# Python:How to select a portion of image between a border using opencv

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing, opencv3.0

i am making a project in which i want to use a particular section of the image but not the entire image,so i want to select that section only.Like for example i can make some frame or border around that section but how will i select it?

Answer (score 1):

In C++ this is done with the `copyTo` function, where you define a ROI and this function then clones every pixel value into a new `cv::Mat`.

For python maybe `numpy.copyto` could work. 
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.copyto.html

You could also make a couple loops to copy pixel by pixel